# Can this [0] mean the whole list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
N1 = ["Ryan",
      "Remariz",
      "Christian" ,
      "Rmefer",
      "Colomn"
]

for names in N1:
    if names[0] == "C":        
        print("* " + names)
```

The outcome will be:

```
* Christian
* Colomn
```

I'm asking because I'm a beginner and I would like to know if that [0] meant the whole list, because I've been trying [2] but it just wouldn't print. No error, and nothing in the output. It took me 15 minutes to figure it out. I know it's a piece of cake to most people but I just started so bear with me.

Comment: No, `[0]` doesn't mean the whole list. But apparently you've figured it out yourself - so what is your question?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

Comment: @General220 Also note that you can edit your own question to fix spelling mistakes, you don't have to add comments for that.

Comment: @mkrieger1 My question was answered. I appreciate you for trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

N1 is simply just a list of names (that are of type String).

When you loop / iterate over your list (`for names in N1`), each loop iteration will then act on that index of the list. So for the first iteration of the loop, `names` is equal to `Ryan` and therefore since you are accessing the 0th index of a string (the first character), `names[0]` is equal to **R** and `names[2]` is equal to **a**.

Hope that helps!

Comment: @ mattdonders That was a very detailed explanation. Thank you so much matt!

Answer (score 1):

After indenting, your exact code works fine:

```
N1 = ["Ryan", "Remariz", "Christian" , "Rmefer", "Colomn" ]
for names in N1:
    if names[0] == "C":
        print("* " + names)
```

In your for loop you are iterating through elements of N1, so names[0] will be the first char of every name.

Answer (score 0):

Your list contains different strings or you can say that your list is made up of array of chars(note that in python there is no concept of array). name denotes the array of chars. By writing name[0] your are telling to fetch the first char of the array. By using for loop you are basically iterating over the strings one by one.0 denotes the first char of the string.

Comment: @samillah_ilyas Thank you so much. I know it was a stupid question but, Oh well.